# Aggregate data loaded in data grid, is there any possibilities?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, datagridview

I read some data and load it into data grid view, I didn't like to change the DB structure and want to aggregate data and load it to another format, save in Excel or Load into another data-grid or any other model.

this is an example:

[image]

we have three type, *a*, *b*, *c* that *a* repeat two times, I want to aggregate result as follows:

[image]

Comment: You need to show some effort first. Research, attempt and then post a question if and when you encounter a specific issue. "I want to do this, tell me how" is not a valid question here.

Comment: If you are using EF, you can use EF's "group by" clause to aggregate as per your requirements. If you are using plan old ADO.Net, you can just "group by" using sql to group records at database level.

Comment: @AmitMittal I study about these two, but I read from XMLREADER.

Comment: @AmitMittal my DB is XML.

Comment: @MinaSoli If you are reading xml into a C# collection, you can do a "group by". This Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304(v=vs.110).aspx and this link https://www.dotnetperls.com/groupby might help you..

Comment: Exactly this is very difficult for beginner like me. thanks @AmitMittal

Comment: Show us your xml input and code that read it.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov which part of code I should share?